# Api gateway with identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, ocelot

I create idenyity server 4 project, create api gateway and api resource
My question
Why need to handle jwt configuration in api gateway although I handled configuration jwt in api resource, I know that api resource communicate with identity server to validate token so why need again handle configuration jwt in api gateway

[image]

I wanna to remove jwt configuration api gateway because I think no need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,you could remove api gateway. Add authentication to apigateway is just for convience if you want to switch to other authentication providers..Just place the `AddAuthentication()` code directly to api project and remove the gateway is all right.